# Video Embedding On Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, video, embedding

Hey I was wondering if it is possible to embed videos into a Visual Basic program and how I should do it. I'm pretty certain it is possible since you can import files and read them, and even play audio media. Thanks in advance for any help

Thom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows Media Player API to do anything it can.

This will tell you how.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562852(v=vs.85).aspx